# Can disabling secure boot affect Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, arch-linux, secure-boot

Can disabling secure boot affect Windows OS? I want to disable it to install Linux. I use Windows 10 as my main OS now so all my data would be potentially lost if there is some problem with Windows after disabling secure boot.

Has anybody experience with this?

Comment: https://www.businessinsider.in/tech/how-to/how-to-disable-secure-boot-on-your-pc-when-you-need-to-install-components-that-arent-compatible-with-the-security-feature/articleshow/81783372.cms#:~:text=Secure%20Boot%20is%20an%20important%20element%20in%20your%20computer's%20security,PC%20and%20leave%20Windows%20inaccessible.

Comment: Why disable secure boot for Linux? It works just fine as long as the certs are installed.

Comment: @Bib While most Linux distros can deal with SecureBoot, not every one of them can. Even a Windows install may need to have it (temporary) disabled if you build your own installation media (e.g. using the RUFUS UEFI NTFS driver).

Comment: If you are using BitLocker, take good note of the recovery key

Comment: Some Linux distributions now come with valid Secure Boot certificates. If yours is one of them, do not disable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Disabling/enabling SecureBoot doesn't affect already installed operating systems in any way.

The only thing SecureBoot (if enabled) does is to verify that the Operating Systems bootloader has a valid security certificate and it refuses to boot it it doesn't have one.

With SecureBoot disabled that check is simply skipped and the UEFI bios will happily load any operating system, regardless of whether or not it has a certificate.

I have personally installed at least a 100 systems (Windows and Linux) with SecureBoot off and enabled SecureBoot later without any issues.
(Had to switch it of because my installation medias are created with Rufus which uses a UEFI NTFS driver that doesn't work under Secure Boot.)

EDIT: As Akeo pointed out in the comments, a few hours after I originally posted this answer Rufus was updated and now works WITH SecureBoot enabled.

Comment: _"which uses a UEFI NTFS driver that doesn't work under Secure Boot"_ The latest version of UEFI:NTFS which is used by Rufus [is Secure Boot signed](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/blob/d5dc8ee5e753e0bd4bea6afa745aeac1acb1d0e8/ChangeLog.txt#L5), so that statement is no longer accurate...

Comment: @Akeo You are right. Actually that latest release of Rufus that fixes the SecureBoot issue was released a few hours after I posted my answer. Time to update my boot-sticks. (Just a matter of replacing the NTFS driver file with the new version. No need to recreate the whole USB stick.)

Comment: Enabling Secure Boot can affect an installed OS: for example VirtualBox on Linux will refuse to boot VMs, as it can't load a kernel module that it needs, because the module is not signed

Comment: Sorry to nitpick, but Rufus 3.17 with Secure Boot compatibility was released on October 23rd, not November 23rd. So, unless I'm missing something, that was really one full month before you posted your answer...